# Two divs into a div to apply hover effect

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <label id="my-button">
        <div class="par">
            <div class="col"><div class="circular"></div></div>         
            <div class="col"><h2>Text1</h2></div>
        </div>
    </label>
    <label id="my-button2">
        <div class="par">
            <div class="col"><div class="circular"></div></div>         
            <div class="last"><h2>Text2</h2></div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
... (more rows)
```

**CSS**

```
.circular {
    width: 105px;
    height: 105px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background: url(imgs/desktop.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    margin: 20px 20px;
}

h2{
    font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #2B1C1C;
    transform: translate(-15%,170%);
}

.col{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

.last{
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
}
.row{
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

So, the idea is, using this "table" in CSS, show some images in div's with some text next to them. One image, one text. The CSS code is mostly some cool effect on the images.

I'm trying to group every couple of image and text into a single div (class="par") to add a hover effect to it.

I tried every single post I found here and several others I found on the internet. I don't know what else should I do. Maybe my CSS is messing with me.

What can I do, guys? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What hover effect are you attempting to achieve? I'm confused by what you'd like to happen when reading your question.

Comment: @schmidt382 simple effect like opacity or change the color, something that makes my feel the mouse is over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a `div` on hover to affect a child, use CSS descendent selectors.

```css
.par {
}

.circular {
  background-image: url(http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg);
  width:100px;height:100px;
  
  opacity: 1;/*this is important*/
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;/*for a fade effect*/
}

.par:hover .circular {
  opacity: 0;/*this is the result value*/
}

.par:hover {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="par">
   <div><div class="circular"a</div></div>
   <div>Text1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add something like this to add hover effect to all .par children:

```
.par:hover *{
 background-color:blue;   
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqt4f1rz/)

Comment: Thank you but the other solution is perfect for my code.